# Printing ip addresses in a loop

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to put together a line with the ip addresses of my cluster in a loop:

```
set_fact: nodelist={%for host in groups['proxmox-cluster']%}"{{hostvars[host].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses|string}}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

But when I try to put this line into a file with

```
 lineinfile:
        path: "/etc/security/access.conf"
        line: "+:root:{{ nodelist }}"
```

I get:

> "[u'192.168.31.238']","[u'192.168.31.248']","[u'192.168.31.252']","[u'192.168.31.250', u'192.168.1.250', u'192.168.32.250', u'192.168.33.250']"

instead of

> 192.168.31.238,192.168.31.248,192.168.31.252,192.168.31.250,192.168.1.250,192.168.32.250,192.168.33.250

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that `hostvars[host].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` is an array. That is why you're printing a joined list of strings inside arrays `"[u'192.168.31.238']","[u'192.168.31.248']"...`

If you only want to print the default ipv4 addresses you can replace your hostvars expression with:

```
hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address
```

If you want to print the first address in the total list of addresses you can replace your hostvars expression with:

```
hostvars[host].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | first
```

If you want to include *all* ip addresses from *all* hosts you will need two loops. This can either be done with Jinja2 template syntax, clever filter chains or both. For example replacing the entire expression with a combination of a jinja2 loop with a filter will give you:

```
{% for host in groups['proxmox-cluster'] %}"{{ hostvars[host].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | join(',') }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Personally I try to avoid mixing Jinja2 template syntax inside ansible tasks/playbooks. There is usually a cleaner way using just filter chains. In your case for example you might do something like this:

```
- name: Print ips in access.conf
  lineinfile:
    path:  /etc/security/access.conf
    line: "{{ groups['proxmox-cluster'] 
            | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_default_ipv4')
            | map(attribute='address')
            | join(',') }}"
```

Comment: Many thanks! I also prefer not to mix that so I followed your suggestion.
And it works prefectly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try simpler version below

```
- set_fact:
    nodelist: "{{ nodelist|default([]) + hostvars[item].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['proxmox-cluster'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a filter on *nodelist* variable in *lineinfile* module:

```
lineinfile:
  path: "/etc/security/access.conf"
  line: "{{ nodelist | join(',') }}"
```